# application is not working on IIS 6.1

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an examination system in ASP.NET which is working fine on integrated IIS. I deployed it on IIS 6.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2, the deployment is fine, But the application is not working i mean when i browse the application in browser it should bring login page which it brings but when i enter the username and password in text boxes and click login button, it does nothing. I search too much over the internet, googled different things but i couldn't find the solutions.

I know it is a silly type of question which i couldn't explain in a better way but please anyone help me.

Comment: Is there an [`IIS 6.1` on Win 2008 r2](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150249.aspx?Windows+Server+2008+with+IIS+6+0)?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Trace information. I am going to assume your Session Keys are not appearing. Ensure your hostname has no underscores, as this interferes with cookies. And ensure on IIS. Session State is enabled

Comment: There is a jquery progresbar plugin that gets executed on login button click to show that the login validation is in progress but even that jquery plugin doesn't get executed. Please not that all of my browsers are up to date.

Comment: Could you check if your cookies on IIS are not set to expire immediatly after? Also look at your Web Browser Security Settings. Mainly the script part, and make sure they are enabled.

Comment: Sir some of the jquery code gets executed but qhen it comes to the ajax call it then stops working

Comment: Do you by chance have Fiddler? So you can see information of the http traffic. And what browser are you using? Try setting the ajax cache to false on your request if it is IE.

Comment: Dear Friend, Problem is solved, I was using Entity Framework and i had set authentication to integrated security = true which i then changed to username and password. It works fine now. Thanks for replying me.